# I need to separate all numbers and characters in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me with solving the above.

String looks like below : 'AB78KH013Hj9'
I should get in this way : num:780139
                           char:ABKHHJ

Comment: sounds like a homework question...

Comment: Do you want to implement this with sql SP or with any programming languages ????

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this with SQL??

Comment: yes. I wanted to do this with sql server. As i am in biggining stage of learning sql, i was givin with few questions like this to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Declare @s varchar(100),@result varchar(100)
set @s='as4khd0939sdf78' 
set @result=''

select
    @result=@result+
            case when number like '[0-9]' then number else '' end from 
    (
         select substring(@s,number,1) as number from 
        (
            select number from master..spt_values 
            where type='p' and number between 1 and len(@s)
        ) as t
    ) as t 
select @result as only_numbers
```

You can also use userdefined function
Refer these links
http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/madhivanan/archive/2007/12/18/extract-only-numbers-from-a-string.aspx
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/11/sql-server-udf-user-defined-function-to-extract-only-numbers-from-string/

Comment: @st varchar(20) set @st = 'AB1H4J7L9K' declare @s int declare @l int declare @vn as varchar(20) set @vn = ' ' declare @vs as varchar(20) set @vs = ' ' set @s = 1 set @l = LEN(@st) while(@s < = @l) begin if (substring(@st,@s,1) IN ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')) set @vn = @vn+substring(@st,@s,1) else set @vs = @vs +substring(@st,@s,1) set @s = @s +1 end

Answer (score 0):

```
string numPart, charPart;
foreach(char c in input)
{
    if(c.islpha())
    {
        charPart = charPart + c;
    }
    else if (c.isnumber())
    {
        numPart = numPart + c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @NumStr varchar(1000)
SET @NumStr = 'AB78KH013Hj9';

BEGIN
WHILE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@NumStr)> 0
    SET @NumStr = REPLACE(@NumStr,SUBSTRING(@NumStr,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@NumStr),1),'')
END

PRINT @NumStr
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH
  filter AS
(
SELECT
  LEN('AB78KH013Hj9') AS remaining,
      'AB78KH013Hj9'  AS input,
  ''                  AS numeric,
  ''                  AS alpha

UNION ALL

SELECT
  remaining - 1,
  RIGHT(input, remaining - 1),
  CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', LEFT(input, 1)) > 0 THEN numeric ELSE numeric + LEFT(input, 1) END,
  CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', LEFT(input, 1)) > 0 THEN alpha + LEFT(input, 1) ELSE alpha END
FROM
  filter
)


SELECT numeric, alpha FROM filter WHERE remaining = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @string varchar(20),@Num varchar(20),@str varchar(20),@i AS INT
SET @string = 'AB78KH013Hj9';
SET @i = 0
SET @num = @string
SET @str = @string

WHILE @i <= len(@string)
BEGIN
    SET @str =  REPLACE(@str,SUBSTRING(@str,PATINDEX('%[^a-z]%',@str),1),'')
    SET @num =  REPLACE(@num,SUBSTRING(@num,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@num),1),'')
    SET @i = @i + 1
END

PRINT @Num
PRINT @str
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
-- In Sql

DECLARE @STRING VARCHAR(20),@NUM VARCHAR(20),@STR VARCHAR(20)
SET @STRING = '1HAR9I9SH7';

SET @NUM = @STRING
SET @STR = @STRING

WHILE(PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@NUM)> 0)
    
BEGIN

SET @STR =  REPLACE(@STR,SUBSTRING(@STR,PATINDEX('%[^A-Z]%',@STR),1),'')

SET @NUM =  REPLACE(@NUM,SUBSTRING(@NUM,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@NUM),1),'')

END

SELECT @STR
SELECT @NUM
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @s varchar(max) = 'AB78KH013Hj9';
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@s, '0', ''), '1', ''), '2', '') [string]
    , REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@s, 'a', ''), 'b', ''), 'c', '') [number]
```

etc.